# How does this seemingly-trivial simplification work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, fractions

In a section on inductive proofs in the book Modelling Computing Systems: Mathematics for Computer Science (Muller, Struth) there is a simplification that is assumed to be trivial, but that I can't figure out.

It occurs in this step:

$$
\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3} + (k+1)(k+2) \stackrel{?}= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}
$$

How does one get from the first expression to the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3} + (k+1) (k+2)
&= \frac{\color{red}{k}(k+1)(k+2) + \color{red}{3}(k+1)(k+2)}{3}\\
&= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(\color{red}{k}+\color{red}{3})}{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I'm kicking myself. Thank you - beautifully laid out too :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Multiply $(k+1)(k+2)$ with $3$ and add $k(k+1)(k+2)$

Then factor out $(k+1)(k+2)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$(k+1)(k+2)=\frac{3\cdot(k+1)(k+2)}{3}.$$ Now combine the fractions and factor out $(k+1)(k+2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the second term with a denominator of 3.

$$(k+1)(k+2)=\frac{3(k+1)(k+2)}{3}$$

Add the two fractions and factor out the common $(k+1)(k+2)$.

$$\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)+3(k+1)(k+2)}{3}=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}$$

There you go!

Answer (score 1):

If boils down to

$$\begin{align}\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3} + (k+1)(k+2)
&=\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)+3(k+1)(k+2)}{3}\\
&=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}
\end{align}$$

Where the last step is just factoring$(k+1)(k+2)$ in the numerator.